# PhoneGap in Android: Inputs do not move with soft keyboard

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I am helping to style a Banking mobile app, and the company is using `PhoneGap` to build across all platforms. I am using a Nexus 4 (android) to test the app, and have noticed that when input fields are tapped, the screen does not scroll up with the soft keyboard - many input fields get lost behind the keyboard.

I can NOT have the addressbar at the top of the screen show, so the one fix I found that said to change the xml file fullscreen preference won't work.

How can this be fixed? I have not been able to test on other devices yet.

Comment: Use [Plugin SoftKeyBoard](https://github.com/hit0907/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard)

Comment: I have never used a plugin before, and there are no instructions on how to implement this. I'm reading up on the documentation now, but a little guidance on exactly how to use this might be best, please! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin suggested in the comments worked.